# Pycharm console font options are grayed and can't be changed

Tags: pycharm

I want to change the font of the **Pycharm IDE** but the changing options are grayed and can't be changed.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't edit the font for any of the stock schemes. You need to click `Save As...`, save Default as its own new scheme (e.g. Ali Custom Scheme), then you can edit the font of that scheme.

Comment: Sweet!  That was driving me nuts, as its not at all obvious :/